# How to replace value in txt file with powershell from GitHub

Tags: powershell

I want to build a simple script that may be useful for others as well, but I have only very basic programming knowledge and can't do it myself without learning how to write powershell scripts from scratch.

What this script is supposed to do is, open an INI file (really just a txt), look for a variable with an assigned value and replace that value from a txt hosted on GitHub, save and then run a program.

This is for the tracker list of qBittorrent, since that feature still hasn't been implemented and the only other script that I could find that does this is for linux and mac, there seem to be none for windows.

The basic idea is this:

```bash
get-content "c:\users\[user]\appdata\roaming\qbittorrent\qbittorrent.ini"
# This is where pseudo code starts
get file from "[github-link.txt]"
save file to cache # keeping it is useless as it gets updated daily
find variable "Session\AdditionalTrackers=" in qbittorrent.ini
replace value of variable with content of cached file # this is what I struggle with most when looking for example code. Everything I could find specified the exact string that needed replacing, which in this case is quite long and may change with every update of the file.
overwrite original file
launch program qbittorrent.exe
end script
```

Conveniently or most likely deliberately all (most) of the tracker lists on GitHub are already formatted in a way that they can be directly pasted into the file without having to worry about formatting. [Example](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ngosang/trackerslist/master/trackers_all.txt).

I can totally understand if nobody wants to do the work, but I would greatly appreciate it and possibly others that are looking for a stopgap for the lacking feature.

If this already exists, go ahead and call me an idiot and while you're at it drop a link ;)

Comment: I suggest focusing your question on your core problem: updating a value in an INI file. It's best to provide sample file content and desired output, along with what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

I just found a little tool called Power Automate and it pretty much does what I was looking for. It's not quite as elegant as a single click script but it does the job. Sadly I can't share the "flow" I built because, well, there is no option for it - thanks Microsoft. So, I'll try my best to write it out.
Not quite a "solution" but pretty to close to it.

Here is the "flow":

```
    get file from web       // from github for example
    read text from file     // read downloaded .txt file
    read text from file     // read qBittorrent.ini
    crop text               // crop between flags in qBittorrent.ini use "Session\AdditionalTrackers=" as start and "Session\GlobalMaxRatio=" as end and save to cropVar2
    crop text               // crop before flag use "Session\AdditionalTrackers=" as flag and save to cropVar1
    crop text               // crop after flag use cropVar2 as flag and save to cropVar3
    replace text            // replace cropVar2 with content of downloaded file and save to cropVar2
    write text to file      // write cropVar1,cropVar2,cropVar3
    end flow
```

Keep in mind that any changes to the qBittorrent.ini may change the order of the entries. Which means you have to check if it's still correct after every update and after every change you make in the options. This is a massive cludge after all...

You can input fail saves so that you won't break anything if the order changed.